# Loop to combine data from columns with non-overlapping NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a database with NBA play by play. To make the database tidy, I'm trying to take two columns (team1, team2) and combine them into one column. These two columns will only have character data in one or the other due to the nature of the data. Therefore, merging them together would not harm data integrity.

I'm still getting the hang of functions so here's what I tried to no avail:

```
for(i in nrow(NBA_Clutch$Washington[i])) { 
  if is.na(NBA_Clutch$Washington[i] == FALSE) { 
    print(NBA_Clutch$Washington[i]) 
  } else { 
    print(NBA_Clutch$Cleveland[i]) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is likely failing because you need to pass a vector to `for` (ie. 1:nrow(NBA...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a for loop at all for this kind of work in `R`. In this case, you can work with the column as a whole:

```
NBA_Clutch$newcolumn <- NBA_Clutch$Washington
NBA_Clutch$newcolumn[is.na(NBA_Clutch$newcolumn)] <- NBA_Clutch$Cleveland[is.na(NBA_Clutch$newcolumn)]
```

If you want to use a `for` loop still, we can do something similar to what you already have:

```
NBA_Clutch$newcolumn <- NBA_Clutch$Washington

for (i in 1:nrow(NBA_Clutch)) { 
  if (is.na(NBA_Clutch$Washington[i])) {
      NBA_Clutch$newcolumn[i] <- NBA_Clutch$Cleveland[i]
  } else { 
      NBA_Clutch$newcolumn[i] <- NBA_Clutch$Washington[i]
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured I could do it a different way but was hoping to better understand how to use for loops and thought this would be a simple task for it to help my overall understanding. Is there a way to do this with a for loop anyway just so I could better understand how for loops work? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I included an answer showing how to do it with the for loop like you had. Note that now the loop goes through a sequence, that `is.na` is enough for the `if` test, and that generally we should have parentheses around the `if` condition.

Comment: I copied this code. The blank variable created first worked, but then it returned an error: object 'i' not found.

Comment: @JeffHenderson Sorry there was a typo, try again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a for loop. You can use `dplyr::coalesce`

```
NBA_Clutch %>% mutate(WA_CL= coalesce(Washington, Cleveland))
```

Or in `base`:

```
NBA_Clutch$WA_CL <- na.omit(unlist(NBA_Clutch[,c("Washington", "Cleveland")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ifelse` function:

```
NBA_Clutch$newColumn = ifelse( !is.na(NBA_Clutch$Washington, 
                               NBA_Clutch$Washington, 
                               NBA_Clutch$Cleveland)
```

The ifelse function works on vectors and is used like this:
`ifelse( condition, true case, false case)`

If you want to use your for-loop change this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(NBA_Clutch)) {
```